# Not able to download the file from Google Drive using googleapis

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, google-drive-api

So I'm trying to download the file from google drive using googleapis V3 but its showing me error of Property **'on' does not exist on type 'GaxiosPromise<Schema$File>'.**

Here's my Code

```
var fileId ='FILE_ID'
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
drive.files.get({
   fileId: fileId,
   alt: 'media'
})
.on('end', function () {    // error here
   console.log('Done');
})
.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error during download', err);
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./static/upload/${fileName}`));
```

follow this code here
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64337805

Comment: Are you trying to download a Google Workspace mimeType document or a different kind of file?

Comment: trying to download mimeType:video/mp4 file size more than 500mb

Comment: @Tanaike I tried that link to but its also give me error  ** Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Schema$File'. **

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current script from `I tried that link to but its also give me error ** Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Schema$File'. **`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide your current script and the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to try to understand about it.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with smaller videos? If the problem is the size - you can download in chunks (partial download) as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I think there's another issue around for it somewhere but as far as I can remember you need to use the response object to pipe the writestream,i.e

```
drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'}, {responseType: "stream"}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    //   handle error
  } else {
    res.data
      .on("end", function () {
        console.log("Done");
      })
      .on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error during download", err);
      })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./static/upload/${fileName}`));
  }
});
```

Comment: already tried this solution it's also shows error **Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Schema$File' **

Comment: if that during runtime or are you using typescript?

Comment: If typescript you can just update the typings, e.g 

import { GaxiosResponse, GaxiosOptions } from "gaxios";
...
drive.files.get(params, options, (err, res: GaxiosResponse<any>) => {
...

Comment: it will show error because res.data.on is not function, after else condition @chrismclarke

Comment: whoops, I missed out the options that should also be set (to specify the responseType as a stream). It should work with this, if not perhaps share a log of what you get if you console.log(res)