# Download PNG image from Google Drive with googleapi

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a image from Google Drive with this code

```js
/**
* @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
*/
function getFile(auth) {
        const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
        drive.files.get({
                fileId: '1A2yXmbspiJUlZ-Xs0R__8fKpVmazjYFQ',
                alt: 'media',
        }, (err, res) => {
                if (err) return console.log('Error during download', err);
                const buf = Buffer.from(res.data);
                fs.writeFile('plot_primos_ln4.png', buf, (err) => {
                        if (err) return console.error(err);
                        console.log('Done.');
                });
        });
}
```

but when I try opening the file, I receive an error telling me the file format is not supported. I tried changing enconding, but doesn't work. Is there a step I'm missing?

Edit: Found this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js.
Helped me already.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js this might help

Comment: @DaImTo I've already tried the code in there before trying the one above and it didn't work. The code above is an attempt at doing something similar to what is shown in here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64337805