# Uploading photos from Google Drive to AWS S3 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

Requirement is to upload photos from a public google drive folder to s3.

Code to fetch images list from google drive

```
module.exports.fetchImageDetails = async (fileId) => new Promise(async (res, rej) => 
{
  const token = await googleUtil();
  const drive = google.drive('v2');
  drive.files.get(
    {
      auth: token,
      fileId: `${fileId}`,
    },
    (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`);
        rej(err);
      }
      res(response.data);
    },
  );
});
```

Iterating over images

```
for (file of fetchedFilesInFolder.files) {
    uploadStatus = await s3Helper.uploadImage(
         process.env.MEDIA_S3_BUCKET,
         url,
         fileDetails.webContentLink
    );
}
```

Upload to S3:
const options = {
uri: url,
encoding: null,
};
const body = await request(options);

```
const uploadResult = await s3
  .upload({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: path,
    Body: body,
  })
  .promise();
```

This code sometime works and sometime not. Many a times, image uploaded on S3 is not a valid image.

We are really not sure, what's happening.

Please Note: Images are around 6 MB in size. Also, google drive *webContentLink* by default download the image when we access the URL (*https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<file_id>&export=download*). Can this be a root cause of problem for `const body = await request(options);`? Also, removing *&export=download* from the link did no wonder as *https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<file_id>* is redirect to another link.

We have already spent enough time on this but couldn't fix it.

Comment: In order to download the image file, it is required to use files.get method instead of files.export method. So, for example, in order to download the image file from Google Drive, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64337805

Comment: @Tanaike we will test that. Thanks.